# ownership of content shared by app user

Tags: facebook

I just can't find any info on what the legal situation is for content of an app provider, when shared by a user.

Does the same apply as in the terms and conditions for users, basically stating that Facebook has all the rights, or is there somewhere specific terms and conditions for app providers? There must be something, as there are newspapers articles being shared and I doubt they allow facebook to do with it as they wish.

In our case, we would like to allow our users to publish a picture with a mix of our pictures, fotos from other sites (with cc-by) and fotos which we would like to retain the rights to. Can someone point me to the right text?

This is what I found on the general terms and conditions:

https://www.facebook.com/terms.php

> 2. Sharing Your Content and Information
>
> You own all of the content and information you post on Facebook, and
>   you can control how it is shared through your privacy and application
>   settings. In addition:
>
> 1. For content that is covered by intellectual property rights, like photos and videos (IP content), you specifically give us the following
>      permission, subject to your privacy and application settings: you
>      grant us a non-exclusive, transferable, sub-licensable, royalty-free,
>      worldwide license to use any IP content that you post on or in
>      connection with Facebook (IP License). This IP License ends when you
>      delete your IP content or your account unless your content has been
>      shared with others, and they have not deleted it.

Comment: When you share something on FB, you grant them right to use it, so they can extract data and publish it through their platform, although you don't quit on your ownership. Anyhow, my best advice is to get *real* legal advice if this really concerns you.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to see first, if they actually have something written down, that I might have missed in my search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it in https://developers.facebook.com/policy/?locale=en_US, number 6. basically they can do as they please...